# Convert int to array char in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a integer number to an array of chars without using String operations.

My attempt was:

```
int number = 12;
char[] test = Character.toChars(number);

for (char c : test)
    System.out.println(c);
```

There is no output, and should give me:

'1'

'2'

How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Go through the implementation of `Integer.toString()` and the related methods.

Comment: Why the restriction on `String` operations?  In my long career, nobody has ever placed such a restriction on me.

Comment: You're mistaken about what `Character.toChars()` method actually does. It "**Converts the specified character (Unicode code point) to its UTF-16 representation stored in a char array.**"  Its `int` parameter specifies "**a Unicode code point**"

Comment: @DavidWallace - Probably homework.

Comment: Ahh!  Teacher preparing them for the real world, where this never happens.  Say no more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
int number = 12345;

char[] arr = new char[(int) (Math.log10(number) + 1)];

for (int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    arr[i] = (char) ('0' + (number % 10));
    number /= 10;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note that `floor(log10(n) + 1)` returns the number of digits in `n`. Also, if you want to preserve your original number, create a copy and use that in the `for`-loop instead.

Also note that you might have to adapt the code above if you plan on also handling non-positive integers. The overall idea, however, should remain the same.

Comment: Yes, but `log10` works with doubles, and could therefore be subject to rounding errors in some implementations.  This implies that there is a risk that the array won't be long enough to store all the characters in some cases.  So this answer is not as good as an answer that just works with integers, strings and characters (like the other three answers here).

Comment: @DavidWallace The implementation should be that defined by [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log10(double)). As for rounding errors, please provide an example of such a case (i.e. a positive `number` for which this does not work).

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that the OP will be using the standard `java.lang.Math`.

Comment: The docs for `java.lang.Math` say that the result will be within 1 ULP of the right answer.  That's not good enough.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ok, so do you have an example for which this does not work? I myself am eager to see one.

Comment: In JDK 1.6.0_45, which is what I have on my PC right now, there are no such examples.  But that is not the point.  A Java runtime could comply entirely with the Java spec, and give an unexpected result for your program.  The fact that one particular Java runtime does NOT give any unexpected results is no excuse for being sloppy about rounding errors.  The very next version that Oracle release may give you the unwanted result, and the fault would not be with them.

Answer (score 1):

`char[] test = Integer.toString(number).toCharArray();`

Comment: *without using String operations*

Comment: I'm leaving this here, because a future SO user may come across this question, while searching for a way to do this same thing, but without the bizarre restriction.  In _their_ case, this is a useful answer, although I freely admit that it doesn't meet the OP's immediate needs.

Answer (score 0):

Extract each digit of the number, convert it into a character(by adding '0') and store them into a char array. Let us know what you have tried.

Comment: I don't think there's a guarantee that '0' is encoded as 48, '1' as 49, and so on.  Depending on that behavior is bad practice.

Comment: @bdares A `char` is a `UTF-16 code unit`. That cannot change.

Comment: I believe there IS such a guarantee - Java defines what encoding is used for its characters.  But for readability, it would be better to add '0' (the character), rather than 48.

Comment: Absolutely, I have never heard java char deviates from ASCII

Comment: Even if that may always be technically correct, it's still not a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @arshajii's code `log10(n) + 1` is something new for me as well. If you intend to use `Vectors` instead of `arrays` you can also follow this procedure(*But the Vector has elements in reverse order*) in which you never need to calculate the size of number itself

```
public static Vector<Character> convert(int i) {
        Vector<Character> temp = new Vector<Character>();
        while (i > 0) {
            Character tempi = (char) ('0' + i % 10);
            i = i / 10;
            temp.add(tempi);
        }
        return temp;
    }
```